# Where is my segmentation fault occuring?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am very new to C, so I apologize if this is a silly question. I am getting a segmentation fault, and when I run gdb, I am not getting a line number to demonstrate what is causing the fault like I usually do. Instead, I get something along the lines of:

> 0x00000000004012ff in find_any_ptr ()

I am writing a method to return a pointer to the first occurrence of any character in `stop` in the given `string`, or `NULL` if `string` doesn't contain any of the characters.

```
char *find_any_ptr(char *string, char* stop){
    char* ch1 = string;
    char* ch2 = stop;
    int retComp = strlen(string);
    char* retChar;
    while(*ch2 != '\0'){
        int temp = 0;
        while(*ch1 != '\0'){
            if(*ch2 == *ch1){
                if(temp < retComp){
                    *retChar = ch1;
                    retComp = temp;
                }
            }
            temp++;
            ch1++;
        }
        ch2++;
    }
    if(retComp == strlen(string)){
        return NULL;    //NULL has been defined elsewhere
    }else{
        return retChar;
    }
}
```

If anyone sees where the underlying issue is, I would really appreciate your help. :) Thank you!

Comment: The crash happens at `*retChar = ch1` because `retChar` is an uninitialized pointer. Compile with `-Wall` on the command line, and your compiler should tell you about things like this. (You probably meant to write `retChar = ch1`)

Comment: Besides the crash, it seems to me that you are getting the algorithm backwards, your outside loop should be on the characters of `string`, the inside loop over `stop`. You don't need all these temporary variables, when you first find a matching character you can return the pointer to where you are in `string` immediately. If you get at the end of the loops it means that you found nothing good, so you have to return NULL.

Comment: Are you compiling with - g flag on before running gdb?

Answer (score 1):

Change `*retChar = ch1;` to `retChar = ch1;` ie. you're dereferencing the `retChar` pointer when it isn't initialized to something and you probably just want it to assign the value of the `ch1` pointer (the address not the char it points to).

Answer (score 0):

The following statement:

```
*retChar = ch1;
```

Causes the segmentation fault because you are trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer; to avoid this, you should change that statement to:

```
retChar = ch1;
```

This statement stores the address of `ch1` in `retChar`, not the `char` value that is stored in `ch1`; this is probably what you are looking to do.

Comment: The `new char` thing you are suggesting serves no other purpose than leaking memory.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Just edited my post, sorry, I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out!